# Run several stored procedures in parallel in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, jobs

I am preparing a job in SQL Server with several steps.

The first 3 steps should run in 'series' (synchronously, i.e not in parallel), the fourth one should trigger 3 other stored procedures to run in parallel (at the same time).

The 3 stored procedures are called:

```
P_ETL_KPI_Fac_DDelivery, 
P_ETL_KPI_Fac_DShipment and 
P_ETL_KPI_Fac_DOrder.
```

To do it, I create 3 other stored procedures called

```
P_ETL_KPI_Fac_DDelivery_Launch, 
P_ETL_KPI_Fac_DShipment_Launch and 
P_ETL_KPI_Fac_DOrder_Launch
```

in which I just put the query to execute the stored procedure; i.e in `P_ETL_KPI_Fac_DDelivery_Launch` I put `exec P_ETL_KPI_Fac_DDelivery`.

And In step 4 in the job I put this code:

```
exec P_ETL_KPI_Fac_DDelivery_Launch
exec P_ETL_KPI_Fac_DShipment_Launch
exec P_ETL_KPI_Fac_DOrder_Launch
```

I am not sure that by doing this the 3 stored procedures (P_ETL_KPI_Fac_DDelivery, P_ETL_KPI_Fac_DShipment and P_ETL_KPI_Fac_DOrder) will run in parallel since `P_ETL_KPI_Fac_DDelivery_Launch` will call `P_ETL_KPI_Fac_DDelivery` and then when `P_ETL_KPI_Fac_DDelivery` finishes, `P_ETL_KPI_Fac_DShipment_Launch` will run.

Is it true? and if yes can anyone has suggestion to run at specific step (not the last one) several stored procedures in parallel?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your 4th step will execute them one after another, the second exec will not start until the first will finish

Comment: You can make SSIS package and put there 3 execution tasks in parallel

Comment: As @sepupic points out, you can make a "master.dtsx" ssis packages with 3 execute sql tasks, which executes your 3 SP. Then they will run parallel.

Comment: You can execute stored procedure asynchronously, using sql server agent (one time immediate task) or sql server  broker (here is great article http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/)

Comment: can't we run a job from a step into another job?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ForEach -Parallel in Powershell. The simple example below will run all stored procedures in a database.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel?view=powershell-5.1

```
Workflow TestRunParallelExecute
{
    $ServerName = "localhost"
    $DatabaseName = "testrun"
    $Procedure_Query = "select name from sys.procedures"
    $Procedure_List = (Invoke-Sqlcmd -Server $ServerName -Database $DatabaseName -Query $Procedure_Query)

    ForEach -Parallel ($Procedure in $Procedure_List.Name)
    {
         Invoke-Sqlcmd -Server $ServerName -Database $DatabaseName -Query $Procedure 
    }
}
TestRunParallelExecute
cls
```

Taken from answer:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223262/powershell-run-stored-procedures-in-parallel-in-database